# Register DLL/OCX in InnoSetup

Tags: dll, installation, inno-setup, regsvr32, dllregistration

I have a DLL and OCX pack then I've decided to make an installer.

This is what I have:

```
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

[Files]
Source: {syswow64}\*; DestDir: {syswow64}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
Source: {sys}\*; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist


[Run]

Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{sys}\zlib1.dll"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: zlib1.dll; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated

Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\actskin4.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: actskin4.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Bassmod.dll"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Bassmod.dll; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\ChamaleonButton.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: ChamaleonButton.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.Calendar.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.Calendar.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.Codejock.TaskPanel.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.Codejock.TaskPanel.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.CommandBars.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.CommandBars.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.Controls.Unicode.v13.2.1.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.Controls.Unicode.v13.2.1.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.Controls.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.Controls.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.DockingPane.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.DockingPane.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.Markup.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.Markup.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.PropertyGrid.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.PropertyGrid.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.ReportControl.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.ReportControl.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.ShortcutBar.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.ShortcutBar.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.SkinFramework.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.SkinFramework.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Codejock.SyntaxEdit.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Codejock.SyntaxEdit.v13.4.0.Demo.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\HookMenu.ocx"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: HookMenu.ocx; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\MSCOMCTL.OCX"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: MSCOMCTL.OCX; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\MSCOMCTL32.OCX"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: MSCOMCTL32.OCX; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\Msvbvm50.dll"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: Msvbvm50.dll; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\msvcr71.dll"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: msvcr71.dll; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
Filename: regsvr32.exe; Parameters: """{syswow64}\zlib1.dll"" /S"; StatusMsg: Registrando: zlib1.dll; Flags: RunHidden WaitUntilTerminated
```

I've seen the regserver parametter but I'm not sure how it works (I've readed the parametter documentation), I need to know if I can simplify the things by doing only this without needing all the [RUN] section?:

```
[Files]
Source: {syswow64}\*; DestDir: {syswow64}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist regserver
Source: {sys}\*; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist regserver
```

And also If I do that then I still need to specify the "ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode"? for the correct registration of the first x64 dll?

> UPDATE:

Maybe this is a better equivalent of the [RUN] section:

```
[Files]
Source: {syswow64}\*; DestDir: {syswow64}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist regserver 32bit
Source: {sys}\*; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist regserver 64bit
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The more correct approach would be:

```
[Files]
Source: C:\yourdlls\x86\*; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist regserver 32bit
Source: C:\yourdlls\x64\*; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist regserver 64bit; Check: IsWin64
```

Note that I've changed the Source dir.  That is because it is an **amazingly bad** idea to source files from your own Windows folder, and even worse to do so with wildcards.  You're just asking for something that will **completely destroy** someone else's Windows installation if you attempt that.

(Also note that you should never install to `{syswow64}`, especially when using regserver.  The lines above will have the same effect of installing into two separate folders but they will actually register things correctly, unlike what you had.)

Comment: as noted in the Remarks at the bottom of http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection - regserver has well qualified version checking in place so I don't think the use of the onlyifdoesntexist flag is warranted. The use of the sharedfile flag almost definitely is.

Comment: Yes, normally when installing to `{sys}` you should use `sharedfile` and not use `onlyifdoesntexist`.  I used the same flags as the original question under the assumption that there was some reason the OP wanted them, but this should not be taken to be a general recommendation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the note that "you should never install to {syswo64}" - why?

Comment: The path used to install will be used when registering COM classes and also when incrementing the shared DLL counts.  The former is mostly harmless; it might confuse some apps that are expecting to see System32 instead but most shouldn't care because both System32 and SysWOW64 point to the same file so it should load correctly either way (as long as you're not mixing up the 32/64 bitness).  The shared DLL count is the main problem -- if some apps use System32 and some use SysWOW64 then they will have separate counts and the file may be deleted when it's still required.

Comment: So it's important that all installers use completely identical pathnames when registering COM components -- and since older 32-bit apps written before 64-bit exists will always use {sys}, the ones that are 64-bit aware have to do the same thing.  (Windows itself takes care of making sure that when a 32-bit app tries to access files in System32 it actually gets the files in SysWOW64 -- but that doesn't help with the registration and shared counting issue.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of the files you are trying to install are from Visual Basic 6. The Inno Setup Knowledge Base has/had a special page about how to correctly install VB6 DLLs and OCXs. As of the time of this writing the web page won't load, but you can easily find it in the Wayback machine at this link:

http://web.archive.org/web/20210516171924/https://jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vb

Here's an excerpt from my own *.iss file showing how to install some DLLs and OCXs. Notice how the files are installed/registered differently in each section:

```
; begin VB6 system files
Source: "stdole2.tlb";  DestDir: "{sys}"; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6; Flags: restartreplace uninsneveruninstall sharedfile regtypelib
Source: "msvbvm60.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6; Flags: restartreplace uninsneveruninstall sharedfile regserver
Source: "oleaut32.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6; Flags: restartreplace uninsneveruninstall sharedfile regserver
Source: "olepro32.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6; Flags: restartreplace uninsneveruninstall sharedfile regserver
Source: "asycfilt.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6; Flags: restartreplace uninsneveruninstall sharedfile
Source: "comcat.dll";   DestDir: "{sys}"; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6; Flags: restartreplace uninsneveruninstall sharedfile regserver
; end VB6 system files
; OCX files the application uses (look at *.vbp file to see which ones are needed):
Source: "ComDlg32.OCX"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: restartreplace sharedfile regserver
Source: "mscomctl.OCX"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Flags: restartreplace sharedfile regserver
; remaining application files:
Source: "..\RSSelect.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "..\RSSelect.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion regserver 32bit
```

As a final note, a common issue online is "where to get" the VB6 required files. If you don't actually have VB6 installed on your PC, search online to try to find a software package that someone developed in VB6, and install it. You don't even have to run/use the software; just the mere process of installing puts the DLLs on your PC.